# grep regex to include the log timestamp

Tags: regex, grep, perl

I'm grepping lots of log files for certain Oracle related errors with ORA-xxxxx error codes. All the log entries start with a Timestamp(eg : 2017-11-29 23:51:46,372). Some of the log entries are multi-line -- like those with java Exception stack traces where the ORA-xxxxx codes are deep down below the log entry line with the Timestamp.

What is the regex to find the log Timestamp all the way to the ORA-xxxxx code ?

Once I get the above regex working, next is to sort them by the date to find the last time a certain ORA-xxxxx Error occurred.

P.S : grep or perl regex command will do.

Thank you,

Example of a log file

```
2017-11-29 23:51:46,013  (Foo.java:67) FATAL - foo.bar()-got exception
during load of zzz javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:76)     .   .   .

        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2235)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1149)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)
        ... 16 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Mercury][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]
       ORA-04031: unable to allocate 3896 bytes of shared
memory ("shared pool","selec t licensekey0_.ID as ID...","sga
heap(1,0)","kglsim object batch")
```

Comment: Look for date to date (not really even necessary to use a regular expression), check whenever the data for that "line" contains `ORA-xx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This perl one liner does the job:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'say $1 while(/(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d+(?:(?!ORA-\d+)(?!\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d+).)*ORA-\d+(?:(?!\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d+).)*)/sg)' file.txt
```

This will print the content of the group 1 (`$1`) every time it found it.

**Options:**

```
-0777   : slurp mode
-n      : add a loop around the script
-E      : enable features ("say" in this case)
```

**Regex:**

```
/                                           : regex delimiter
  (                                         : start group 1
    \d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d+      : regex for date
    (?:                                     : start non capture group
      (?!                                   : negative look ahead, make sure we don't have the following
        ORA-\d+                             : literally "ORA-" followed by digits
      )                                     : end lookahead
      (?!                                   : negative look ahead, make sure we don't have the following
        \d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d+  : regex for date
      )                                     : end lookahead
      .                                     : any character
    )*                                      : non capture group is present 0 or more times
    ORA-\d+                                 : literally "ORA-" followed by digits
    (?:                                     : start non capture group
      (?!                                   : negative look ahead, make sure we don't have the following
        \d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d+  : regex for date
      )                                     : end lookahead
      .                                     : any character
    )*                                      : non capture group is present 0 or more times
  )                                         : end group 1, contents in "$1"
/sg                                         : regex delimiter, s: single line, g: global
```

**Input file example:**

```
2017-11-29 23:51:46,013  (Foo.java:67) FATAL - foo.bar()-got exception
during load of zzz javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
       ORA-04031: unable to allocate 3896 bytes of shared
memory ("shared pool","selec t licensekey0_.ID as ID...","sga
heap(1,0)","kglsim object batch")
2017-11-29 23:51:46,013  (Foo.java:67) FATAL - foo.bar()-got exception
during load of zzz javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
      (NO ORA.....) unable to allocate 3896 bytes of shared
memory ("shared pool","selec t licensekey0_.ID as ID...","sga
heap(1,0)","kglsim object batch")
2017-11-29 23:51:46,013  (Foo.java:67) FATAL - foo.bar()-got exception
during load of zzz javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
       ORA-04031: unable to allocate 3896 bytes of shared
memory ("shared pool","selec t licensekey0_.ID as ID...","sga
heap(1,0)","kglsim object batch")
```

**Result:**

```
2017-11-29 23:51:46,013  (Foo.java:67) FATAL - foo.bar()-got exception
during load of zzz javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
       ORA-04031: unable to allocate 3896 bytes of shared
memory ("shared pool","selec t licensekey0_.ID as ID...","sga
heap(1,0)","kglsim object batch")

2017-11-29 23:51:46,013  (Foo.java:67) FATAL - foo.bar()-got exception
during load of zzz javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
       ORA-04031: unable to allocate 3896 bytes of shared
memory ("shared pool","selec t licensekey0_.ID as ID...","sga
heap(1,0)","kglsim object batch")
```

The second block is not displayed

Comment: thanks very much. Not all log entries will have the same strucutres. Some of the entries will have the ORA-XXXXX in the same line as timestamp. others will have 3-4 newlines and others will have more. Can I have 1 regex to satisfy all conditions ? thanks very much.

Comment: @anjanbacchu: It should work for all these cases.

Comment: thank you. I've accepted this answer. Now, I've asked the 2nd part of this question at https://superuser.com/questions/1278651/script-to-find-latest-log-entry-for-a-given-ora-xxxxx-code. Care to try ? thanks again,

Comment: Is there a way to output **only ** the timestamp given a particular ORA-xxxx code ?

Comment: @anjanbacchu: See my answer to the other question.